# Los backgrounds del css no aparecen en la web

Tags: html, css

los backgrounds en el codigo del css no aparecen en la pagina web, es decir ahí están sus colores respectivos. Es para un juego que estamos haciendo llamado "hamster philosophy" he querido mejorar la pagina web, adaptarla al diseño responsive y este ha sido el resultado.

¿Cómo podemos hacer para que se vean en la pagina web?

Muchas gracias

Cada div es un segmento de la pagina web, dichos div serian `#section1` , `#section2`, `#section3`

Y al momento de agregar los colores usando sus `ID` no se aplican correctamente al fondo.

```css
#photo {
    width: 292px; height: 468px;
}

#section1 {
    background-color: #FFB2B2;
}

#section2 {
    background-color: #FFFACC;
}

#section3 {
    background-color: #A5D8D8;;
}

#profile {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Styles CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <title>Hamster Web!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="section1">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: auto; padding: 60px;">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="photo" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-7KHdebczOYg/XSiP7VRl_ZI/AAAAAAAAAFM/Lbs2aJH6JSUa_wqxMX-k4eVxKDv06IeEQCLcBGAs/s1600/12321321321.gif" class="card-img" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title">Hamster Philosophy</h3>
              <p class="card-text">Hello there! We created this game for you, for us and for everyone. We are independent developers and we like you to give a chance to this incredible adventure! Fly for your life and please try to not to crush with any dead-mouse out there! pd: the download button is just right down</p> <p>(BETA, try it for free) ↓ ;)</p>
              <p class="card-text"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Download for Googleplay</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download for Windows</button></small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="section2">
       <h3 class="card-title">Gameplay!</h3>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L2kSibl98ic" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div id="section3">
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: auto; padding: 60px;">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img id="profile" src="https://i.imgur.com/H9w8Dju.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Hamster Philosophy</h3>
                  <p class="card-text">Hello there! We created this game for you, for us and for everyone. We are independent developers and we like you to give a chance to this incredible adventure! Fly for your life and please try to not to crush with any dead-mouse out there! pd: the download button is just right down</p> <p>(BETA, try it for free) ↓ ;)</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Download for Googleplay</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download for Windows</button></small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <footer><small><p>Copyright 2019. Contact: Luisjoselopezd@gmail.com</p></small></footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He revisado tu código. En tu css estas declarando que `.card` tenga un `background-color:#fff` y `.card` esta por encima de `#section1 #section3` y por eso no se visualiza el fondo que le aplicas

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase .card de boostrap establece un background #fff  y .card es un div que está encima de #section1 y #section3 por lo que no verás el fondo aplicado a menos que establezca en el css:

```
.card {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario! Me funciono!

Comment: Listo! disculpe era mi primera pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Revisé el css de Bootstrap y hay un css que hace que reemplace el `background-color` de estos section, y es que como tienes un elemento div dentro de estos sections con la clase `.card`, y en el css de Bootstrap se establece estos `.card` a `background-color: #fff;`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!